# Delphi Split a string containing several records with various delimiters

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-7

I am looking to split a string containing several records into individual items in a stringlist.  (Delphi 7.)

Here is the raw text in a single long string:

> +CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:05+08"This is the text in message 1+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:30+08"And this is the text in message 2+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:58+08"This is the text in message 3+CMGL: 3,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:33:19+08"And finally text in message 4+CMGL: 4,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:34:03+08"Ok one more the the text in 5th messageOK

I received it from a GSM device.  The final character 2 characters are always OK, being the result from my GSM  device.

This is the result I require:

```
+CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:05+08"This is the text in message 1
+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:30+08"And this is the text in message 2
+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:58+08"This is the text in message 3
+CMGL: 3,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:33:19+08"And finally text in message 4
+CMGL: 4,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:34:03+08"Ok one more the the text in 5th message
```

(each +CGML is the start of a new line)

I can work with it from here as it is uniform.  I would appreciate any help.  I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PosEx` and `Copy` functions to build a function to split the string.

Check this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  StrUtils,
  SysUtils;


const
  GSMMessage=
  '+CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:05+08"This is the text in message 1+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:30+08"And this is the text in message 2+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:32:58+08"'+
  'This is the text in message 3+CMGL: 3,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:33:19+08"And finally text in message 4+CMGL: 4,"REC UNREAD","+27832729407",,"12/03/17,21:34:03+08"Ok one more the the text in 5th messageOK';


procedure SplitGSMMessage(const Msg : String; List : TStrings);
const
 StartStr='+CMGL';
Var
 FoundOffset : Integer;
 StartOffset : Integer;
 s           : String;
begin
  List.Clear;

    StartOffset := 1;
    repeat
      FoundOffset := PosEx(StartStr, Msg, StartOffset);
      if FoundOffset <> 0 then
      begin
       s := Copy(Msg, StartOffset, FoundOffset - StartOffset);
       if s<>'' then List.Add(s);
       StartOffset := FoundOffset + 1;
      end;
    until FoundOffset=0;

    // copy the remaining part
    s := Copy(Msg, StartOffset, Length(Msg) - StartOffset + 1);
    if s<>'' then List.Add(s);
end;

var
  List : TStrings;
begin
  try
    List:=TStringList.Create;
    try
     SplitGSMMessage(GSMMessage, List);
     Writeln(List.Text);
    finally
     List.Free;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: +1 But in instead of `while true do` I would prefer `repeat until FoundOffset = 0` which eliminates the need for break.

Comment: @NGLN while True is good here. It means you can test FoundOffset against 0 just once rather than duplicating the test. I'd prefer the original.

Comment: @David So the original is faster? I didn't realize that. Does it mean the while condition is never tested again?

Comment: @ngln speed is not the issue. It's more about simplicity, readability and maintainability. Simpler code is easier to verify and less likely to have bugs. That's what we all strive for.

Comment: @David Ok, then we disagree on what version is the simpler code.

Comment: @ngln at the very least the repeat until version should put the result of the termination test into a local variable to avoid duplication of that test

Comment: Thank you very much, the help is appreciated.  Nice to know there is a place to get answers when i get stuck.

Comment: @user1276138, that's the whole purpose of StackOverflow... Welcome aboard!